# How to achieve autocomplete dropdown using struts2-dojo-plugin

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, autocomplete, dojo

I want to implement autocomplete dropdown using `<sx:autocompleter>` in struts2.

The following are the use jar's

```
struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar
struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.2.1.jar
```

The ajaxAutocomplete.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<s:form action="ajaxAutoCompleteActionForm" id="ajaxAutocompleteActionForm">
<H1> Bulk Action Form </h1>
<sx:autocompleter size="1" list="countries" name="country"></sx:autocompleter>
</s:form>
```

After deploying the above code simply shows a normal dropdown with list of countries. There is no `<input>` field to enter the text.
I want to achieve the same behaviour as shown in the following link

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-ajax-tutorial-example-d…

Also in my console I am getting the following error

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: djConfig is not defined"
```

What I am doing wrong? How to avoid the console error?

How to get the dropdown with text box to search select option value?

Comment: Read again that tutorial and follow it to the point.

Comment: Also consider joining the new decade and using struts2-jquery-plugin's autocompleter that is newer, better and supported. Dojo plugin is deprecated since *years*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add head in `ajaxAutocomplete.jsp`

```
<head>
 <sx:head/>
</head>
```

put this before your form tag.